Deferred mortality probabilities (mortality table)
My question has to do with drawing correct conclusions regarding deferred mortality probability from a mortality table.
I am looking at the table below (source). In it, the $q_x$ (2nd columns) is given, whilst the $p_x$ I've computed simply as $1-q_x$.

Goal
I would like to find an answer to the following question: for a life age 50 ($x$), what is the probability that this life will survive until 51 ($x+1$), 52 ($x+1$), 53 ($x+1$), 54 ($x+1$), 55 ($x+1$) ... That's my goal.
I've watched this (very good) youtube video that seems to offer a recipe for precisely this kind of calcs. However... I struggle with something conceptually quite fundamental in it.
Problem With Understanding
Let me use an example:

This life surviving one year (i.e., reaching its 51st birthday) is easy, and the $p_{50}$ can be obtained directly from the table as 0.994692.
However, how about this life surviving until its 52nd birthday? If I would follow the argument from the video (which, granted, is for someone surviving some time, and then dying, but I assume the argument/mechanism goes the same way for the question that I ask), I should say: this life surviving until 52 is equivalent to it surviving until 51, and then from 51 until 52, and this can be expressed as $p_{50} \cdot p_{51} = 0.994692 \cdot 0.994314$. This is, at leats, how I understand the argument from the video. But ... wouldn't this imply that the two events (surviving until 51 and surviving until 52) are independent? Clearly, in order to have a shot at surviving until 52 one must survive until 51, so to me the dependency is rather obvious ... Yet, the multiplication of the two probabilities - the $p_{50} \cdot p_{51}$ - and assuming that this is the answer, looks as if the two events were not dependent???

Ask
How should I approach the task at hand? What formula to use, and if the one with the "simple" product, how can this be justified - especially from the conditional probability standpoint, please?

The survival rate for going from your 50th birthday to your 52 birthday is the product of the survival rate from 50 to 51 times the survival rate from 51 to 52. This is just the arithmetic of survival rates when you go through 2 sequential processes.  Imagine that you have to pass 2 exams one after the other, the first of which is passed by 99.4692% of students and the second is passed by 99.4314%.

Your calculation is fine. Let $X$ denote the age of death. You can calculate $P[X>52] = P[X>52 \text{ and } X > 51] = P[X>52 | X > 51]\cdot P[X>51] = p_{51} \cdot p_{50}$ using the basic property of conditional probability.
